# HERE. Destination Weather: Observation product - rainfall never has a value

Tags: here-api

I have tried the Observation API with many different locations. Those that have Rain or similar conditions, always have no value for the rainfall  - it is always missing in the response. Same for all the precipitation1H etc values. There is essentially no precipitation values in the observation as far as I can see. Is it a bug?

Comment: Can you please add some location for reference which you tried so far.

Comment: OK. This is changing all the time and might not be the case when you look at it of course. But I have 2 examples, Stockholm (Light Rain) and Gotland (Scattered Showers). Both have no rainfall member in the response, and the other precipitation members are just *. Here are the requests:

https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=observation&latitude=59.3294&longitude=18.0687&metric=true&oneobservation=true

https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=observation&latitude=60.4833&longitude=12.0667&metric=true&oneobservation=true